# How do I use an if statement to know whether the player or the computer won?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I just started learning java so I may not even be on the right track but I have an assignment that asks me to create a game of 21. The way the game works is that a player and computer take turns entering either a 1, 2, or 3. The player that enters a number that meets or exceeds 21 loses. The trouble I seem to be having is that I cannot seem to get the program to exit the loop when the final number is entered and it will display that the player loses every time, win or lose.

I have tried using another if statement after the do-while loop to display either "You Win!" or "You Lost." However, I can't figure out what parameters I should use in the if statement to decide who won. I also tried to set the game up with the player as even numbers and the computer as odd numbers but I couldn't get the numbers to add to a running total to end the loop.

```
  int numLoops = 0;
  int firstCheck;
  int points;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  do
  {
     System.out.print("\nEnter a 1, 2, or 3 >> ");
     points = input.nextInt();

     int random = (int )(Math.random() *  3 + 1);
     numLoops = points + numLoops + random;

     if(numLoops < 21)
     {
        System.out.println("The computer entered a " + random);         
        System.out.println("The new total is " + numLoops);
     }
     else
     {
        //This is what always prints.
        System.out.println("You lost! The computer is the victor.");
     }
  }while(numLoops < 21);
  //this is what I am having most of my trouble with.
  System.out.println("You Win!");
```

I expect that the loop will close after the total reaches 21 and will output a statement That varies based on who won. However, the program always outputs that the player lost.

Comment: The `else` clause always gets printed because `numloops` always starts out less than 21.  I think the solution is just to move that whole `if` clause outside of the loop.  You want to loop until one player is at or over 21, then fall out of the loop.  After the loop, check once who busted and the other player is the winner.

Comment: One way to design a program like this is to try to do the steps by hand.  Go through a simple game like this on a tabletop and write down the steps you go through each time.  That will help you understand what the computer needs to do at each step.

Comment: One common solution to things like `if-else` not working is to step through the code using a debugger, and you should learn to use one.  However I think the problem here is the design, so a debugger will help you see what the code is doing, but it won't really show you what the code should do instead.  For that, you have to be able to manually design the steps of the program.  But sometimes a debugger can show you where a program deviates from what you want it to do, and that can give you a clue where you went wrong in the manual design stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If have made a few changes to simplify things. Have a look at the source code, it should be well documented and explains things best.

```
/*
 * Which players turn is it?
 * (true for human player, false for computer)
 */ 
boolean isHumanPlayersTurn = true;
int totalPoints = 0;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// the game ending condition
while (totalPoints < 21) {

    // take an action, depending on the players turn
    if (isHumanPlayersTurn) {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a 1, 2, or 3 >> ");
        totalPoints += input.nextInt();
    } else {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
        System.out.println("The computer takes " + random);
        totalPoints += random;
    }

    System.out.println("Total amount is " + totalPoints);

    /*
     * Important part: After each players move, change the players turn, but do NOT
     * do this if the game already ended, since then the other player would have won.
     */
    if (totalPoints < 21) {
        isHumanPlayersTurn = !isHumanPlayersTurn;
    }
}

// now, the player to move is the one who loses
if (isHumanPlayersTurn) {
    System.out.println("You lost! The computer is the victor.");
} else {
    System.out.println("You Win!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the user enters a number, you should check immediately to see if they hit 21 (and also output the total at that point). If 21 was not hit, then the computer should guess, and then you check again to see if 21 was hit. So you'll have two if statements (one after each guess; user/computer). In the else block after the user guess is where the computer would guess. Your if statement will check for >= 21, indicating a loss for the user or computer as appropriate. You won't need to declare a victor outside of the loop as this can be done inside the loop...

For example:

```
    int total = 0;
    do
    {
        System.out.print("\nEnter a 1, 2, or 3 >> ");
        points = input.nextInt();
        total = total + points;
        System.out.println("The new total is " + total);

        if (total >=21)
        {
            System.out.println("You lost! The computer is the victor.");
        }
        else
        {
            int random = (int )(Math.random() *  3 + 1);
            total = total + random;
            System.out.println("The computer entered a " + random);         
            System.out.println("The new total is " + total);

            if(total >= 21)
            {
                System.out.println("You Win!");
            }
        }
    }while(total < 21);
```